# 500 error in cfc

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I am getting a 500 error when I try calling a method in a cfc.  Since I am not getting any kind of debugging information, I am struggling to figure out what is going on.  I have looked at the logs, and nothing is there that would indicate what is going on.  I am using jquery `.ajax` to call the cfc using `POST`

Here is the jquery:

```
$("#edit_button").click(function(){
    if(theArray.length > 0){
        theJson = JSON.stringify(theArray);
    }
    $.ajax({type:"POST",
            url: "/CFCs/fund_profile.cfc?method=updateProfile",
            data:theJson,
            dataType:"json",
            success:(function(response){
                var content = ''
                response = JSON.parse(response);    
                alert("the response is" + response);
        });
    });     
});
```

The the method in the cfc is pretty basic right now:

```
<cffuntion name="updateProfile" access="public" returnFormat="json">
    <cfargument name="theJson">
     <cfif isJson(theJson)>
         <cfset var theArray = deserializeJson(theJson)>
         <cfset var passingJson = serializeJson(theArray)>
     </cfif>
     <cfreturn passingJson>
```

here is the stack trace:

```
500

javax.servlet.ServletException
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:154)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doPost(CFCServlet.java:289)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.http.WebService.invokeRunnable(WebService.java:172)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

I'm stumped, and without any kind of real debugging information to go on, I'm stuck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CFC's method's access attribute needs to be remote for Ajax calls (or from something like a Flex app's service). Essentially, without the access set to remote, the method in question is not "available" when that call is made.

Try:

```
<cffunction name="updateProfile" access="remote" returnFormat="json">
  ...
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I tried that, before thinking that was the problem, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok. It does have to be remote, though :). Have you tried using the $.getJSON (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) call from jQuery (versus $.ajax): 
$.getJSON("/url/or/path/to/your/cfc.cfc", {
    method: 'update_profile',
    theJSON: yourdata,
    returnformat: 'json'
}, function(data){ alert(data); });

Comment: I haven't.  I will give it a try.  I'm pretty new to jquery, so this is all trial and error (more errors than I would like to admit :) ).

Comment: I hear that Rob! I'm certain it's safe to say we all went through these pains ;).

If you stick with the $.ajax call (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), consider setting the dataType property to "json" o r"jsonp" (you set the data but not the dataType prop in your original post).

Comment: That worked.  Thank you. But could you explain why, if you could, why using `$.getJson` instead of `$.ajax`? They seem to do the same thing, but the `$.getJson` is just a `$.ajax` call but shorted specifically for json's.  Is that correct?

Comment: what does firebug/chrome dev tools say? My issue with this is normally that I left debugging on and it won't connect because of that.

edit: sorry, didn't notice your issue was resolved.

Comment: @mrbusche, I get exactly what I put in my original post.  I pulled that out of the firebug console.

Comment: Rob: Without having tested, my sense is that it was one of a couple of things "missing" from the $.ajax call: (a) the remote value for the access attribute in the CFC and either (b) the lack of a "dataType" property OR (c) adding &returnFormat=json to the URL property.

Comment: @craig.kamisnky, I'll give it a shot. I added the dataType, and still threw the same error.  I'll the `&returnFormat=json` to the url string, and see what happens, but I got the `$.getJson` "working", meaning it returned without errors.

Comment: @RobM - Well, I'm just glad that $.getJSON is working for you! I looked back over some of my older jQuery and CFC code and noted that I only ever use $.getJSON in these scenarios and now I cannot recall whether or not that was because I had an issue with $.ajax :).

Comment: Added it, still the same problem.  Looks like I'm going with `$.getJSON`.